# How to get content from cliboard in built in apps in android

Tags: android, clipboard

How can I get content from clipboard (not only text) like the built-in apps (messaging, browser) does in adroid?
Please be advise, that I don't have in mind pasting text from clipboard (not only). Pictures below should clearify what content I want to get.

Pic.1 This menu pops up when I longClick TextEdit - "Schowek" means literally Clipboard in Polish.
[image: This menu pops up when I longClick TextEdit]

Pic.2 This what shows when I click "Schowek" from the popup.
[image]

How to get similar content in my app like in Pic.2 ?? My phone is Samsung Galaxy S5 with Android 4.4.2 onboard.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this link on android developer website:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html

Comment: This is not helpfull at all. Content in clipboard is not changed when calling copy image from eg. Built-in browser